# PHP keeps picking up last element of radio buttons

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have the following problem:

I'm submitting my data from radio buttons to a ajax request so I can move the data to the database.

-html

```
<form class="siteInfo" action="ajax/site.php?nr=<?php echo $_GET['nr']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="transport_transport_id" value="1"> <span class="value">1</span><br/>
<input type="radio" name="transport_transport_id" value="2"> <span class="value">2</span><br/>
<input type="radio" name="transport_transport_id" value="3" tabindex="21"> <span class="value">3</span><br/>
```

-The page that ajax posts to

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if(!empty($val)) {
        $result[$key] = $val;
        //This should be passed to database update function
    }
}

var_dump($_POST);

$site->setSiteFields($siteNumber, $result);
```

-The ajax

```
$('.siteInfo').on('change', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};


    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The ajax returns the response it gets from the pickup page but doesn't matter what radio button I pick, I only get the last value returned. Anybody can tell me what goes wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `name="transport_transport_id[]"`

Comment: Well to give you an idea of why it is happening, you have 3 fields with the same `name` attribute. So when it assigns that in your javascript, it is assigning `data['transport_transport_id']` 3 times. Because you can't have duplicate keys in javascript, only the last value is kept. You could do a condition to check if the radio button is checked, then only assign the value if it's checked.

Comment: use `data: $("form").serialize()` instead of building your data youself.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Still get return the following:  array(1) {
  ["transport_transport_id"]=>
  string(3) "3[]"
} And if it is a possibility I would like to keep the name the same. This matches the database field it has to be inserted

Comment: Do you want to send the checked value or all.??

Comment: @EatPeanutButter: pointless. they're radio buttons. only ONE of the set can ever selected and be submitted.

Comment: Good call @MarcB. I'm inclined to go with @cmorrissey and wonder why OP doesn't just use `.serialize()`

Comment: Can somebody tell me who just deleted an answer here? Because it was the right answer...

Comment: Welcome, deserved it. But after deleting your answer It took me a bit to find out who posted that answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.siteInfo').on('change', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};


   data[name] = that.find("input[name='transport_transport_id']:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Works! is it fixable on within php?

Comment: `<?php echo $_POST['data']; ?>` will give you the checked value

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. The answer you gave works. But the question was if this issue also could be fixed serverside?